# Heap space error in eclipse, How to overcome this in eclipse.ini

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse configuration is described below,

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1400m
```

I am using ubuntu with 6 gb of memory, please give me some best configuration for eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 1):

Increase value for -Xmx parameter.